# When to use lambda-s3 and when to use s3-lambda from @aws-solutions-constructs in Typescript?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk-typescript

I noticed there are two different [AWS Solutions constructs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/constructs/welcome.html) for s3 bucket and lambda

- [LambdaToS3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/constructs/aws-lambda-s3.html)
- [S3ToLambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/constructs/aws-s3-lambda.html)

Reading the documentation I couldn't understand what is the difference between them.

Are these to aliases of each other or they are made for different use cases?